# How to Run Py.test in PyScripter

Tags: python, pytest, pyscripter

I am a newbie to py.test , Please let me know how to run the py.test in PyScripter Editor.
I have tried in the belwo way but it doesn't work.

import pytest

def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 5

pytest.main()

and on running the above script i get an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 474, in main
    exitstatus = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 422, in __call__
    return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 433, in _docall
    res = mc.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 351, in execute
    res = method(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\main.py", line 107, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\main.py", line 92, in wrap_session
    config.pluginmanager.notify_exception(excinfo, config.option)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 285, in notify_exception
    res = self.hook.pytest_internalerror(excrepr=excrepr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 422, in __call__
    return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 433, in _docall
    res = mc.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\core.py", line 351, in execute
    res = method(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\terminal.py", line 152, in pytest_internalerror
    self.write_line("INTERNALERROR> " + line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\_pytest\terminal.py", line 140, in write_line
    self._tw.line(line, **markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py-1.4.11-py2.7.egg\py\_io\terminalwriter.py", line 181, in line
    self.write(s, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py-1.4.11-py2.7.egg\py\_io\terminalwriter.py", line 225, in write
    self._file.write(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py-1.4.11-py2.7.egg\py\_io\terminalwriter.py", line 241, in write
    self._writemethod(data)
TypeError: 'AsyncStream' object is not callable
```

Pleae do help me

Comment: Does it run outside of PyScripter? What version of PyScripter are you using?

Comment: Yes it runs out side the PyScripter if invoke the script in the belwo way  "python -m py.test sample.py". i am using pyscripter 2.5.3

Comment: Sounds like a PyScripter compatibility issue...I'd report the problem to them. From the traceback it looks like pytest is encounters some kind of "INTERNALERROR" when run from within it. Meanwhile try something else (or nothing at all -- just use a text editor and the command line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script appears to be wrong , as far as i know pytest.main can be used if you want your pytest should be run by python interpreter. You need have have your test under a directory.
For example your pytest file is called test_sample which has following content
===================================pytests/test_sample===============================

```
    import pytest
    def func(x): return x + 1
    def test_answer(): assert func(3) == 5
```

==================================================================================
Then you can have the following code in python file which runs your test_sample

```
   pytest.main(args=['-s', os.path.abspath('pytests')])
```

This should solve your problem

If you dont want python to run your pytests you can configure pyscripter runner to be run by pytests via tools-->configure tools and then add the pytests command line argument. you can then run you pytest from tools. By default pyscripter uses python interpreter as runner

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytest in pydev :
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-pydev/0.1

Comment: with this i will able to configure Pydev on Eclipse but not pyscripter. Please Help me as how to run in PyScripter.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like PyScripter sets some sys.stdout stream that pytest does not recognize.  I just tried to refine the handling from pytest's side.  You can try using it with:

```
pip install -i http://pypi.testrun.org -U pytest
```

which should in particular install also the "py" lib which contains the TerminalWriting code.  If that doesn't work, please [file an file](http://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issues/new) with the exact environment/PyScripter version you are using. And also the value of "import py ; print py.**version**".

HTH,
holger

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytest,os
os.chdir("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Development\Python\<test_pytest.py>") #your file location
pytest.main(['-s', 'test_pytest.py'])
```

save the file . On Pyscripter go to ***Run-->Python Engine--> Internal*** 
Run the test , it should work.
Somtime pyscripter doesn't pick up the change, you may have to reinitialise the python engine (Ctrl+F2)